# Variable in a while($row loop

Tags: php

Can i put a variable inside this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

ie

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) and color = '$color')
```

I basically am calling a query but want to report on it in sections - in this case color by color. So i'd like to loop around all my colors variables running the while loop for each one

Comment: have you tried the code - what result does it give you?

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried?

Comment: well the above gives me a syntax error so i thought maybe i couldnt

Comment: OK - resolved it - thanks for the input

Comment: Aren't you suppose to compare rather than assign? You might have to change `color = '$color'` to `color == '$color'`

Comment: should have put up my solution - you are correct Steward but a bit more as well
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) and $row['Color'] == $color)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though you'll have to change it later if you want a different value in each iteration.

For eg. The following code:

```
<?php
  $i = 0;
  $var = "red";
  while( $i++ < 10 && $var = "white" ) {
    echo $i . " " . $var . "\n";
  }
?>
```

will give you the `$var` as white for all 10 iteration values.

You can see the result [here](http://codepad.org/4ORo1iPA) on [codepad](http://codepad.org/4ORo1iPA).

---

Since, you are fetching the `color` from your table, your code should instead be:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    $Mycolor = $row['color'];
    // more code
```

Comment: not sure i understand how that works with mine

for me:

color is a field name in the table that is fetched into $results